# Django - user is_active

Tags: django, django-authentication

This is my user authentication method:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                print('TEST')
                messages.info(request, 'Inactive user')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username/password!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/login.html', {})
```

If user exists and is not active wrong message appears:

```
messages.error(request, 'Invalid username/password!')
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

instead of:

```
print('TEST')
messages.info(request, 'Inactive user')
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

I don't have any idea what is wrong here... Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried `User is not None` yet?

Comment: Yes I tried it.

Comment: Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) including a login view. You don't have to write your own!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default `ModelBackend` authentication backend started rejecting inactive users in [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#django-contrib-auth). Therefore your `authenticate()` call returns `None`, and you get the *Invalid username/password!* message from the outer if/else statement.

As Daniel says, if you use the default `ModelBackend`, you no longer need to check `user.is_active` in your login view.

If you really want `authenticate` to return inactive users, then you can use [`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend) instead. If you do this, then it is your responsibility to check the `is_active` flag in your login view.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

Comment: I tried this and solved the problem, one question though. are there any downsides with using this?

Comment: @IsaacHatilima it can useful to set `is_active=False` to prevent a user from logging in. If you change this then you’ll lose that ability. Whether that’s a downside depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

The call to `authenticate` already checks that the user has the is_active flag set, and returns None if not. There is no need to check it separately.

Comment: How then I check if user exists but is inactive?

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: I am just learning Django and since there is "is_active" flag I would like to know how can I use it.

Comment: One reason might be to display validation error for a disabled / inactive user to inform them that they are no-longer active?

Comment: in django 1.9, ``authenticate`` won't check ``user.is_active`` but in django 2.1 this is automatically checked.
see [django 1.9 doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) and [django 2.1 doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active)